# Visual Studio C++ Issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I always programmed on xcode, but after finally switching back to PC, I decided to use Visual studios; however, one problem I'm encountering is that it won't read my whole program at times. For example. I could have a program aht just displays "Hello", and it'll show that, but when I modify it, and add other things to the same program it won't recognize the rest of the program and when I build, and run it it'll just display "Hello", even though there's other lines of code.

Here's a program I was trying write

```
      #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

void DisplayInput(string[], string[], char [], double[], double[], double[], int);
void Calculation(double, double, double, double[], double[], double, double, int);

int main()
{

    int const size = 3;
    string F_name[size], L_name[size];
    char Mi[size];
    double HoursWorked[size], Rate[size], Gross[size], Net[size];
    double StateTax, FederalTax, UnionFees, Sum, Avg;

    DisplayInput(F_name, L_name, Mi, HoursWorked, Rate, Gross,  size);
    Calculation(StateTax, FederalTax, UnionFees, Gross, Net, Sum, Avg, size);

    system("pause");
}

void DisplayInput(string F_name[], string L_name[], char Mi[], double HoursWorked[], double Rate[], double Gross[], int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << " What's your first name " << endl;
        cin >> F_name[i];

        cout << "What's youtr last name? " << endl;
        cin >> L_name[i];

        cout << "Enter your middle initials. " << endl;
        cin >> Mi[i];

        cout << "How many hours did you work " << endl;
        cin >> HoursWorked[i];

        cout << "What is your hourly rate " << endl;
        cin >> Rate[i];

        double TimeHalf = 1.5;

        if (HoursWorked[i] < 0 || HoursWorked[i] > 60)
        {

            cout << " Wrong entry " << endl;

        }

        if (Rate[i] < 0 || Rate[i] > 50)
        {


            cout << "Number needs to be between 1 and 50 " << endl;


        }

        if (HoursWorked[i] <= 40)
        {

            Gross[i] = HoursWorked[i] * Rate[i];

        }

        else if (HoursWorked[i] > 40)
        {

            Gross[i] = HoursWorked[i] * (Rate[i] * TimeHalf);

        }




    }

}

    void Calculation(double StateTax, double FederalTax, double UnionFees, double Gross[], double Net[], double Sum, double Avg, int size)
    {


        StateTax = Gross[size] * 0.06;
        FederalTax = Gross[size] * 0.12;
        UnionFees = Gross[size] * 0.02;
        Net[size] = Gross[size] - (StateTax + FederalTax + UnionFees);

        Sum = +Gross[size];
        Avg = Sum / size;



    }
```

Yet when I run it, all I get is it asking me for the name, last name, and not the hours worked or rate, or any of the other lines of code I have in this program. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this? It's happened a few times this week, and  a work around was to save the program, and restart Visual Studios, but I did that again today and it's not working.

Comment: Improve the question title please. Make it describe the problem.

Comment: Did you actually rebuild your project? Did it complete successfully?

Comment: How do I edit the title? Yeah I keep pressing build, and start debugging.

Comment: If the code you posted is what you tried to build, how is it going to build successfully with an incomplete `for` loop?

Comment: When you *build*, Visual Studio will only *compile* the software units that have changed.  It will link all the software modules before creating an executable.  If there are errors, a *new* executable will not be generated and if you debug, you will be debugging an older executable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's not complete code. I'm sure my program has errors, but that's the thing, it won't even tell me if there's an error. I do have a for loop, I'll try adding the whole program.

Comment: Offtopic:  Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of arrays.  Vectors are easier to pass.  Also, pass them by reference or constant reference.

Comment: Offtopic:  Prefer to place variables in a structure and pass one structure to a function instead of many variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately professor wants us to do this whole program with just arrays. We'll start learning vectors next month. Which is making this program a bit of a pain, we'll alos start learning structures, and classes next class(no pun).

Comment: Ran the program. I get no output because the debugger halted execution over use of an uninitialized variable. I received a compiler warning for the error. Running a release loud outside of the debugger may do just about anything, including giving no output because it crashed. If you are not receiving warnings, check Project-Properties->C/C++->General->Warning Level and turn it up a notch or two. Turning on Treat Warnings As Errors is a good idea as well because then you have to resolve the warnings.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah I just fixed the uninitialized error. Thanks! Off topic: How can I like comments?

Comment: One way to like comments is to debug a lot other peoples code who don't use comments (and single letter variable names).  Also, try debugging your own code after a couple of months working on other projects.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I meant to say like people's comment here on STack Overflow. (i.e you helped me out, I like the fact you helped me out) lol.

Comment: Hover your mouse to the left of a comment. A little flag under a triangle should appear. Click the triangle to upvote the comment. Click the flag and fill in a report if the comment is odious or evil. Or in my usual case an off-topic attempt at bad humour.

Comment: @user4581301 that's what I tried earlier, and didn't work. I think it said something about not having enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're project isn't building correctly

if you see this message box it means that there were errors in your code[image]

if you just press yes, it will run the previously successfully compiled build. so it sounds like you are doing this. If you see this message, press no and check your code.

Comment: I tried building, debugging, nothing works, I know my program has errors, and yet it won't show me errors.

Comment: @ReMaKe: By errors do you mean compiler errors, linker errors or run-time errors?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews after pressing just about every button under build, and debug, I finally got an error pop up. Which tells me that the variables, StateTax, Federal, Union, Sum, Avg, are not initialized.

Comment: Ah, that just means you can't pass variables that have no value to `calculation` try `double StateTax = 0, FederalTax = 0, UnionFees = 0, Sum = 0, Avg = 0;`

Comment: @AdamM. that worked. That's interesting. Never knew that.

Comment: @AdamM. last question I have, for PC would you say Visual studios is one of the best compilers? Or should I be using something else? Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, Visual studio is an IDE (Interactive Development Environment). It is, in my opinion, one of the best for productivity and debugging. I would recommend it to anyone.

Comment: There are other good compilers for the PC:  GNU, CLang, Greenhills, Intel.

Comment: And it is not called "Visual studios". Not sure why people keep referring to it as such, when that label appears nowhere on the product.